# ANTLR: parsing header followed by binary data chunk with unknown length

Tags: antlr, grammar, binary-data, variable-length

There in a data stream are two packets. Each has the header followed by some binary data with unknown length, until another header is found, or EOF is reached.
Here is the data: **HDR12HDR345** 
**HDR** is the header marker
**12** and **345** are the binary data.

And here is my current wrong grammar:

```
grammar TEST;

parse   :   STREAM EOF;
STREAM  :   PACKET*;
PACKET  :   HEADER DATA;
HEADER  :   'HDR';
DATA    :   .*;
```

The first header token is recognized, but the **data token is too long** and it consumes the next header and data.

After three days of looking for the solution I did not found any, which matches   both, "binary data" and "unknown length" aspects. But stil I think that this must be some common scenario for parsing. ANTLR is not as easy as it looks like for the first sight :(

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Without anything directly placed after `.*`, ANTLR will consume as much as possible (until the EOF). So the rule:

```java
DATA : .*;
```

should be changed (there has to be something *after* `.*`).

Also, every lexer rule should at least match a single character. But your `STREAM` rule could potentially match an empty string, causing your lexer to create an infinite amount of empty string tokens.

Lastly, ANTLR is meant to parse *textual* input, not binary data. See [this Q&A](http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=binary%20data#query%3abinary%20data+page:1+mid%3aexdeejogzf3zqmko+state%3aresults) on the ANTLR mailing list for more info, or [do a search on the list](http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=binary+data).

### EDIT

Besides placing something after the `.*`, you can also perform a bit of "manual" look ahead in the lexer. A small demo how you can tell ANTLR  to keep consuming characters until the lexer "sees" something ahead (`"HDR"`, in your case):

```java
grammar T;

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "HDR1 foo HDR2 bar \n\n baz HDR3HDR4 the end...";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(input));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean hdrAhead() {
    return input.LA(1) == 'H' && 
           input.LA(2) == 'D' && 
           input.LA(3) == 'R';
  }
}

parse  : stream EOF;
stream : packet*; // parser rules _can_ match nothing
packet : HEADER DATA? {System.out.println("parsed :: " + $text.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));};
HEADER : 'HDR' '0'..'9'+;
DATA   : ({!hdrAhead()}?=> .)+;
```

If you run the demo above:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar TParser
```

*(on Windows, the last command is: `java -cp .;antlr-3.3.jar TParser`)*

the following is printed to the console:

```
parsed :: HDR1foo
parsed :: HDR2barbaz
parsed :: HDR3
parsed :: HDR4theend...
```

for the input string:

```
HDR1 foo HDR2 bar 

baz HDR3HDR4 the end...
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it the "something" something like: "Dear ANTLR look forward for HEADER token occurrence. If you find it, start parsing a NEW token from there?"

Comment: More or less. The `.*` needs to stop before the next `'HDR'`.